# rails carrierwave generated url for STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, sti

I have 1 STI class inherits from `User` class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end

class Staff < User

end
```

but when I looping all the staffs user including the image url like this:

**controller**

```
@staffs = Staff.all
```

**view**

```
<ul>
<% @staffs.each do |staff| %>
<li>
  <%= staff.name %>
  <%= image_tag staff.avatar_url(:small) %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

this code:

```
<%= image_tag staff.avatar_url(:small) %>
```

it will generate upload url like this:

```
/uploads/user/avatar/44/avatar1.jpg
```

instead of

```
/uploads/staff/avatar/44/avatar1.jpg
```

How to do this? thank you

Answer (score 0):

mount the uploader also inside the Staff.

The Problem is, that the Uploader ins mounted on the User. Even if you STI the Staff, for CW its still a user.

Comment: still the same bro, I have add the mount uploader to the staff class, i restart the server then I reupload the image.

Comment: then go into the carrierwave uploader and use instead the model-class the model-type for the url